# Picture not showing up on GitPages, but works perfectly on local host

Tags: html, css, github, localhost

I'm new to website design and I'm building a website for the company I work for. My site works perfectly on my local host, exactly how I wanted it to... but I am facing a problem with the top banner not showing up at all on my GitPage. (and also my favicon stopped working somewhere along the way and I didn't notice).

In my style.css, I've set the background image to a picture (Topbar1.png), and have it so that it is a different picture on smaller screens (Topbar2.png). [located in style.css lines 83 and 89].

Neither of these are working on Gitpages. I've looked for different solutions on Stack Overflow, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

This is a link to my [repository:](https://github.com/dkirov1/MDTRedesign)

And a link to my [GitPage:](https://dkirov1.github.io/MDTRedesign/)

-I'm pretty sure my relative path is correct--I'm coding in VS code and this is how their autocomplete feature writes the path when I am selecting my pictures--but I did try different paths just in case.

-I have tried renaming the files (being very careful to use the exact case) and also tried using a different files altogether to see if that would show up. I checked the repository on GitHub to make sure the code is written and uploaded exactly how I had written it. I can also go into my repository and click on the files and the pictures do show up.

-I've cleared my cache and even tried making a different repository with the same files to see if the GitPage would work differently. I've also tried opening my GitPage on my phone and a different computer. It's definitely not working, and since I've been working on this problem over different a couple of days, it is definitely not just GitPages being slow to reflect my changes.

My favicon, (the file I've named mIcon.jpg) was definitely displaying in the beginning and I broke it, but going through my history hasn't been able to help me pinpoint exactly what I did to make it stop working. [located in index.html line 13].

I'd really appreciate the help, I don't understand how it can work on localhost, but not on GitPages and I don't know anybody IRL who can help me with this problem.

Edit: the css code

```
#topbar {
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( #000000, #8b0000);
  background-image: url("/assets/img/Topbar1.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px)  {
  #topbar{
  background-image: url("/assets/img/Topbar2.png");
  background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a URL starting with `/` resolves to the root folder of your domain. It is not a **relative** path

Comment: So this file is located in assets>img>Topbar1; Am I writing the path incorrectly? My github repository has the same structure as my local files, wouldn't that make the path the same?

Comment: In you css file, try adding repo name `MDTRedesign` in url e.g. `background-image: url("/MDTRedesign/assets/img/Topbar1.png");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you open `Developer Tools` and go to `Console` you can check where the website looks for the missing resources. In your case its trying to locate the image here: https://dkirov1.github.io/assets/img/Topbar1.png

But the correct url should be:

https://dkirov1.github.io/MDTRedesign/assets/img/Topbar1.png

To fix that, in your css, instead of using:

```
background-image: url("/assets/img/Topbar1.png");
```

Use:

```
background-image: url("../img/Topbar1.png");
```

Same goes for Topbar2.png.

Regarding the favicon, change:

```
<link href="/assets/img/mIcon.jpg" rel="icon">
```

To:

```
<link href="assets/img/mIcon.jpg" rel="icon">
```

Comment: This worked for me! I will have to do some more research on root folders and absolute and relative paths. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @DianaKirov You're welcome :) A good [reference](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) about file paths